# Most elegant way of including AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox-os

At the moment, I'm including all of my JavaScript files in the `<head>` part of my html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-csp>
    <head>
        <!-- ... -->
        <script src="js/lib/wiki2html.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/lib/es6-promise.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/lib/l10n.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/lib/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/lib/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/lib/angular-touch.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/wrapper-indexeddb.js"></script>
        <script src="js/wrapper-devicestorage.js"></script>
        <script src="js/util.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app-services.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app-directives.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app-controllers.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body data-ng-app="FireDict">
        <!-- ... -->
    </body>
</html>
```

I thought about using build and packaging tools together with tools like `require.js` or browserify, but most of my dependencies don't come as npm modules or as requirejs definitions. I have never used any js build tools before, but it seems to be a lot of work if not all of your dependencies come in the right modularized/packaged format.

**What is the most elegant way to include AngularJS and the other scripts I'm using?**

Some background: I'm authoring a webapp for Firefox OS based on AngularJS. (The problems about ngCsp that I previously described here were due to my ignorance of `angular-csp.css`. I simply forgot to include it.)

Comment: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>

Comment: why dont you use a build tool and concat/minify everything?

Comment: @Yang Li: The truth is: I find it much easier to debug stuff if I don't have to rebuild everything after every little change to the code. And that's why I don't concat/minify everything. Furthermore, I would have to dive into JS build tools etc. But you are probably right.

Comment: By the way, concatenating everything doesn't solve my issue about the `data-ng-csp` directive. I tried this! This problem is really mysterious...

Comment: I use bower to install JS dependencies and [wiredep](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wiredep) to inject them into the page via a gulp task.

Comment: @thomas is it a packaged app?

Comment: Yes, it's a packaged app, see http://github.com/tuxor1337/firedict and https://marketplace.firefox.com/app/firedict

Comment: @thomas You can use something like Grunt or Gulp to minify your scripts on save with a watch command. You shouldn’t be including dozens of JavaScript files like you are currently.

Comment: @MartinBean Why shouldn't I include dozens of JavaScript files? Since it's a packaged app, the js engine can directly access them from an offline location. Therefore loading times should be small anyhow. Correct me if I'm an ignorant fool ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would take a second look at RequireJS. With RequireJS not all of your packages need to be formatted as AMD modules. In the case where a dependency is not in the RequireJS (AMD) format you would instead use the [shim configuration](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) for those dependencies in your RequireJS configuration.

Comment: But NONE of my dependencies use the AMD format. I don't understand how this would be elegant in any respect?!

Comment: [Here's a simple demo I put together and upload to Github](https://github.com/bbone87/require-js-angular-demo) -- it might make more sense to see it. As far as the shim goes for modules not written in AMD format, you only need to add the shim if you want the require statement for that module to return the modules global variable or that module has libraries it's dependent on that need to be loaded before it.